# How to check if a directory is under svn version control?

Tags: linux, bash, svn

From a linux bash script, how can I verify if some directory is under svn version control? I am using svn version 1.7.9.

When I try the following

```
pushd ${WD}; svn info; popd
```

and check the error code I always get a zero, because `popd` succeeded, even if `svn info` returned an error. How to perform a check on a directory in the following way?

```
if [ ... ]; then
    echo "Directory ${WD} not under version control"
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the return code from the `svn` command in a variable and test that-:

```
pushd $PWD
svn info
ERR=$?
popd 
if [ $ERR -ne 0 ];then
    echo "Directory ${WD} not under version control"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Subversion uses a hidden directory called `.svn` (just like `.git` for Git).

First, a directory *not* under SVN control:

```
riemann$ if [ ! -d ".svn" ]; then echo "Directory not under version control"; fi;
Directory not under version control
riemann$
```

Next, a directory which is under SVN control ([Crypto++ use SVN](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SVN)):

```
riemann::cryptopp$ if [ ! -d ".svn" ]; then echo "Directory not under version control"; fi;
riemann::cryptopp$
```

And:

```
riemann::cryptopp$ ls -al .*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jwalton  staff  6148 Jul 20 06:46 .DS_Store

.:
total 440904
drwx------  462 jwalton  staff     15708 Aug 10 16:00 .
drwx------   59 jwalton  staff      2006 Aug 10 15:50 ..
drwx------    7 jwalton  staff       238 Jul 17 07:41 .svn
...
```

Comment: I have updated the question as your suggestion does not work; I do not have a `.svn` directory. Maybe its depending on the version?

Comment: Subdirectories in SVN 1.6.x and earlier all had a .svn and could be used like a full working copy on their own. In 1.7 and higher, only the working copy root has such a directory.